# Change font size of all children form WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making an application in C# using WinForm. I would like to be able to resize the font of all the label inside this application using ctrl + scroll. 
For the moment, I'm able to change the font of all the label inside one form, but I would like to apply this font size modification to all the form and not only the current form.

To create all the form, I'm using a template:

```
public partial class TemplateForm : DockContent
{
    static public UInt16 percentageFontSize = 100;
    public TemplateForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TemplateForm_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            percentageFontSize += 10;
            if (percentageFontSize >= 2000)
            {
                percentageFontSize = 2000;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            percentageFontSize -= 10;
            if (percentageFontSize <= 10)
            {
                percentageFontSize = 10;
            }
        }
        SetAllControlsFont(this.Controls);
    }

    public static void SetAllControlsFont(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection ctrls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
        {
            if (ctrl.Controls != null)
                SetAllControlsFont(ctrl.Controls);

            ctrl.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8* percentageFontSize / 100);

        }
    }
}
```

Each "documents" use this template:

```
public partial class Form1 : TemplateForm
{
    public AccForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : TemplateForm
{
    public AccForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

"this.Controls" only grant me access to the control of the selected form. I think I could achieve this by getting all the control of the form using the "TemplateForm" but I'm not able to find out how to do it. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: You should override `OnMouseWheel`, but what you're doing now would nonetheless work on controls added to the derived Form. What is `DockContent`? Shouldn't `TemplateForm` derive from `Form`?

Comment: DockContent is used as a "docking manager" and derive from `Form`.
What I do doesn't work on controls added to the derived Form. Even if `percentageFontSize` is `Static`, it only updates the controls of the focused form and not all the derived form.
Could you elaborate about overriding `OnMouseWheel`, please ?

Comment: You can override `WndProc` in the derived Forms and trap a custom message or WM_FONTCHANGED, which is sent from the base Form's `OnMouseWheel` override. When the message is received, call `SetAllControlsFont(this.Controls)`. This method (it belongs to the base Form) should be `protected internal`, while `percentageFontSize` must be `protected static int`. The change will be immediate. That's all.

Comment: If it's more comfortable, you can also override WndProc of the base Form and do everything in there, if you don't already override WndProc in the derived Forms for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason that the font size doesn't change on the other forms, and only changes on the current one, is because the other forms have no way of knowing that the size has actually changed, you have to add a way to notify them so they can update the font size as well.
For that, you can use an EventHandler (or create your custom event handler), add it to your TemplateForm class and subscribe to it in the constructor, You raise the event whenever there is a font change and in the trigger method, you update the font accordingly.
All in all your code should look something like this:

```
    static public EventHandler fontSizeChangedEvent;
    static public UInt16 percentageFontSize = 100;
    public TemplateForm()
    {
        MouseWheel += TemplateForm_MouseWheel;
        fontSizeChangedEvent += FontSizeChanged;
    }

    private void TemplateForm_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //// rest of code .....

        fontSizeChangedEvent.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        SetAllControlsFont();
    }

    public void FontSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Only update for the other forms, not the one that raised the event
        if (sender != this)
            SetAllControlsFont();
    }

    public void SetAllControlsFont(ControlCollection ctrls = null)
    {
        if (ctrls == null)
            ctrls = this.Controls;

        //// rest of code .....
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This work well, although, it's not really smooth but it does the work. I will try to improve it to get a fast/smooth result as VS documents size change.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you design has a notion of "the one and only font of all labels". Whenever you think of the one and only, you should think of either a static class, or a singleton. Both have their advantages and disadvantages. Which one you choose is out of scope of this question

Anyway, this one and only LabelFont, has a method to change the font, and once set, an event is raised.

```
class LabelFont
{
    private Font labelFont; // TODO: consider to initialize with a proper default value.
    public event EventHandler LabelFontChanged;

    protected virtual void OnLabelFontChanged()
    {
        this.LabelFontChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public Font LabelFont
    {
        get => this.labelFont;
        set
        {
            this.labelFont = value;
            this.OnLabelFontChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

We need a method with input a sequence of controls, and output: this sequence of controls plus all child controls and grandchild controls, etc

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> ToDecendants(this IEnumerable<Control> controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        // first return this control
        yield return control

        // then return decendants of the child controls
        IEnumerable<Control> decendants = control.Controls
            .Cast<Control>();
            .ToDecendants();
        foreach (Control decendant in decendants)
        {
            foreach (Control decendant in decendants)
                yield return decendant;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you can do something with LINQ and SelectMany. Don't forget to add the control itself, not just the children (which SelectMany would do)

Every TemplateForm needs to be notified whenever the one and only LableFont changes

```
class TemplateForm
{
    private static LabelFont LabelFont => ... // get either static, or singleton

    public TemplateForm()
    {
         ...

         // get notified when the LableFont changes
         LabelFont.LabelFontChanged += OnLabelFontChanged;
    }

    // TODO: Dispose: desubscribe from LabelFontChanged

    private void OnLableFontChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelFont labelFont = (LabelFont) sender; // if singleton, otherwise use static
        Font labelFont = labelFont.LabelFont;
        IEnumerable<Control> decendants = this.Controls.Cast<Control>
            .ToDecendants();

        foreach (Control decendant in decendants)
        {
             decendant.Font = labelFont;
        }
  }
```

Or if you only want to update the font of Label controls:

```
IEnumerable<Control> labelDecendants= this.Controls
    .Cast<Control>
    .ToDecendants()
    .OfType<Label>();
```

Comment: It's not really "the one and only font of all labels" but more a multiplier that can increase/decrease. Although, some label can have different font size.

Comment: even if you want to set the font to only specific values: there is still a font that everybody has. It is "the" current font. I only made it more generic. It is a separate procedure that decides which font size is the current one. If later on you also want to select bold, or times new roman, or whatever, the rest of the procedures don't change

Comment: I see. And do you think this method is faster than the solution proposed by Ayoub_B ? As I commented under his solution, it's not really smooth because it take some time to resize all the label, panel, groupbox, etc. which are set to "AutoSize = true"